# NSDictionary checking for "<null>" value in ios10

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have `NSMutableDictionary` which stores data comping from database.
some keys inside `NSMutableDictionary` has null values like the one shown below.

I wanted to check for null values. I am doing as below:

```
UserMobileNo = "<null>";
UserAccNo = "<null>";
 if(!([dicUserdata valueForKey:@"UserMobileNo"] == [NSNull null]))
        //Saved result
```

but above code do not seems to be checking for null values perfectly.
what is the perfect way of checking null values inside dictionary?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://nshipster.com/nil/

Comment: You can't store null/nil in an NSDictionary; what does your dictionary contain? Literally the string "<null>"?

Comment: yeah as data comes from database.....

Comment: Then you should just compare the string I.e. `=="<null>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to check.

**Using `nil`:**

```
if([dicUserdata objectForKey:@"UserMobileNo"] == nil){
    // found null
}
```

**Using `isEqual` method:**

```
if([[dicUserdata objectForKey:@"UserMobileNo"] isEqual:[NSNull null]]){
    // found null
}
```

*isEqual:Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver and a given object are equal.*

**Using `==` operator:**

```
if[[dicUserdata objectForKey:@"UserMobileNo"] == [NSNull null]]){
    // found null
}
```

**Using `isKindOfClass` method:**

```
if[[dicUserdata objectForKey:@"UserMobileNo"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull null]]){
    // found null
}
```

*isKindOfClass: Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an instance of given class or an instance of any class that inherits from that class.*

Answer (score 1):

```
if (![[dicUserdata valueForKey:@"UserMobileNo"]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
{
     //Not Null
} else {
     //Null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need check to as below:

```
if ([[dicUserdata objectForKey:@"UserMobileNo"]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these conditions:

```
if(!([[dicUserdata valueForKey:@"UserMobileNo"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])) {

}

or

if([dictUserData[@"UserMobileNo"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
   //execute your condition
}
```

Comment: Your syntax is a bit of, you should not use the dot syntax for methods. Also `isKindOfClass` expects an `class` and you are passing a object. Use `[NSNull class]`

Comment: oh..thanks for a mistake.....I showed you swift and objective-c mix...wait m update it

Answer (score 0):

You have interpreted the if condition in a wrong way

can use

```
if ([dictResponse objectForKey:@"UserMobileNo"] != [NSNull null]) {
     //handle your code   
}
```

**or**

```
if (![[dictResponse objectForKey:@"UserMobileNo"]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
      //handle your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
if ([[dicUserdata objectForKey:@"UserMobileNo"] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    // found null
}else{
    // your code
}
```

Comment: question is not to check dictionary to check null value. has already the dictionary and parsing it

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of doing this, i.e. ensuring the value is not `nil` and not `NSNull` is:

```
if (dictionary[key] && dictionary[key] != [NSNull null]) {
  // not nil or NSNull
}
```

Extra checks are unnecessary.